# Hidden child div visible on mouseover of parent

Tags: css

How to make **visibility:visible** of a child div when hover on parent div which is hidden by default ?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">A</div>
    <div class="child2">B</div>
    <div class="child3" style = "visibility:hidden">C</div>
</div>
```

From above code i want child3 to be visible on mouse over of div.parent

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Attach a `:hover` event to `.parent`, select the child `.child3` and change its `visibility` property to `visible`.

```css
.parent > .child3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.parent:hover > .child3 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">A</div>
    <div class="child2">B</div>
    <div class="child3">C</div>
</div>
```

---

You could also do this using `:last-of-type` selector to select the last child. This way you won't have to use different classes.

```css
.parent > .child:last-of-type {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.parent:hover > .child:last-of-type {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">B</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ram You should move the `visibility:hidden` to your CSS file as chipChocolate has put it, don't do it inline in the HTML. If it has to be inline for some reason, you would have to set the hover to `visibility: visible !important;` to force it to override the inline style, which isn't a good practice